# How to count quantity with data in table, depending on status?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a table that records printer paper activities. I need to find the amount of paper in the warehouse, for this I need to add the numbers with the value "arrived" and subtract the values "given" from them. How to do it?

```
ID Name Number Status
000001 Stock 50 Arrived
000002 105-1 2 Given
000003 108-3 1 Given
000004 Stock 10 Arrived
000005 104-1 3 Given
```

It should be 54 (+50-2-1+10-3).

My code:

Views.py

```
class PaperReportView(ListView): 
    model = PaperReport
    template_name = 'paper_list.html'
    ordering = ['-dateaction'] 
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            paper_left=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(status='Arrived', then=F('amount')),
                    When(status='Given', then=-F('amount')),
                    default=0,
                    output_field=IntegerField(),
                    )
                )
            )
        return queryset

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['paper_left_sum'] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('paper_left'))['paper_left__sum']
            return context
```

Models.py

```
class PaperReport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Office', max_length=255)
    amount = models.IntegerField('Number')
    status = models.CharField('Status', max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('paper_list')
```

paper_list.html

```
<h2>Printer paper left: {{ paper_left_sum }}<h2>
<div>
  {% for case in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>{{ case.amount }} pcs {{ case.status}} for {{ case.name }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

Override you get_queryset() and annotate `paper_left` which is the calculated sum of Arrived-Given,

```
# views.py
from .models import PaperReport
from django.db.models import Sum, F, Case, When, IntegerField

class PaperReportView(ListView): 
    model = PaperReport
    template_name = 'paper_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            paper_left=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(status='Arrived', then=F('amount')),
                    When(status='Given', then=-F('amount')),
                    default=0,
                    output_field=IntegerField(),
                    )
                )
            )
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['paper_left_sum'] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('paper_left'))['paper_left__sum']
        return context
```

and in you template file,

```
<h2>Printer paper left: {{ paper_left_sum }}<h2>
<div>
    {% for case in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>{{ case.amount }} pcs {{ case.status}} for {{ case.name }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[Read more about conditional expressions in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is an error: TemplateSyntaxError at /paper_list/
Could not parse the remainder: '(Sum('paper_left'))' from 'object_list.aggregate(Sum('paper_left'))'

Comment: sorry, please check the updated answer..

Comment: the same error: Could not parse the remainder: '(Sum('paper_left'))['paper_left__sum']' from 'object_list.aggregate(Sum('paper_left'))['paper_left__sum']'

Comment: Oh my bad, can you check it once more, now i have updated the get_context_data() method as well

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but I can't see any updates. Also, I copied your code and there is the same error

Comment: now its updated, please check it and let me know

Comment: Now there are no any errors, but it's empty instead of sum. Just "Printer paper left: ". And I changed in models.py to `amount = models.IntegerField('Number')` and rewrote all records. But it doesn't work.

Comment: can you update the question?

Comment: I updated the code in the question

Comment: bro its working on my machine.. once try the answer, because in your views the get_context data is having some extra indentation its inside the get_queryset, but it shoud be outside

Comment: Yes, it works now. I really appreciate your effort!